# How to create a path.length.hist diagram?

Tags: r, igraph

With igraph/R I would like to create a diagram that shows the path lenght histogram.
I can get the histogram values through `path.length.hist`-command, but don't know how to plot the results. 
Would be great if you someone could help me to find the right code for that.

These are the values:

```
 $res
    [1]   7058  83638 124106  97151  43111   4630    354      7

    $unconnected
    [1] 32447
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it is what you want to achieve, but you can try something like that :

```
tab <- as.table(path.length.hist(g)$res)
names(tab) <- 1:length(tab)
barplot(tab)
```

[image]